# Jcarousel design problem

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Excuse me.

I am using jcarousel for nice sliders. so I have got two sliders on my web page.

The first slider is greater than second. so i need modify the separation between images in second slider without modify css (The css is for all sliders in webpage).

However when I modify margin-right in jcarousel-item:

- If the jcarousel wrap is circular break the slide.
- If the jcarousel wrap is normal slide until end of div.

How i modify jcarousel st

Comment: Grammatically, your question is very difficult to understand.  However, regarding circular wrap being broken, I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a documented issue by the jCarousel developer that **wrap:circular** is broken and won't be fixed until the next release.

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/search?q=circular

https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/182

Comment: Thanks for this! Was about to hack on the code a bit but it sounds like it has been an issue for a while and will be fixed in the new 0.3 version (whenever that is released).

Answer (score -1):

When I ran into this problem, I changed to jQuery Cycle Plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

It was annoying to re-implement the image slider again, but it works well in all the major browsers.